# How do I scrape mouse hover-box content on an ajax webpage using Python

Tags: javascript, ajax, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have been trying to extract the dimension for each cell on a map from this ajax [website](http://www.aptaexpo.com/apta2017/public/eventmap.aspx?shmode=E&thumbnail=1), the details for each cell only pop-up when a mouse point on the cell.

I have used Python selenium webdriver and phantomjs to load and extract the page_source but the data wasn't found. I used firebug to look for any .json file that the content may be loading from but found none.

Please take a look at the site and suggest how I can scrape the content from the hover-box displaced when pointing on each cell on the map.

P.S: I have done a lot for research both on stackoverflow and several sites all to no avail.

Comment: How can I also inspect the element for the hover-box displaced when pointing on each cell?

Comment: Do you need to scrape just `Size` value, like `20 x 30` ?

Comment: I will like to scrape the entire content of the hover-box. But suggestion on how to get just the size value will also be helpful. since i can get the other information from the exhibitor list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `AJAX` actually, but `svg` object that contain `<g>` element for each item (booth) on page. To get required info you have to perform mouse hovering over this `<g>`. With following code you could get most of item descriptions (about 2/3 of whole `g` elements number)... I don't know for sure what's context of page is about, so I cannot determine regularity of items appearance on page:

```
from selenium import webdriver as web
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = web.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.aptaexpo.com/apta2017/public/eventmap.aspx?shmode=E&thumbnail=1')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('polygon')[0].click() # [1] to choose another hall 
time.sleep(5)

list_of = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="leaflet-overlay-pane"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]')
for item in list_of:
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(item)
    try:
        description = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[*[contains(text(), "Booth:")]]'))).text
        print(description)
        action.perform()
    except:
        action.perform()
```